# Some apps crash on x86 android eeepc 4G (701). Why and what can I do?

Tags: wireless-networking, android, x86, gopro, gopro-wifi

I installed [x86 android](http://www.android-x86.org/) on my [asus eeepc 4G 701](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asus_Eee_PC#Eee_700_series) and it was a success out of the box!

Then I installed the [gopro app](http://gopro.com/software-app/gopro-app/) for my camera to connect and control it via wifi.

The pc cannot maintain a connection to more than one wifi network. It is either connected to my internet wifi or the gopro wifi.

Also, when I want to detect/use my camera from the app it just shuts down.

Do you have any idea why that happens and what I can do about it?

Comment: I have never heard of Android using multiple connections at once.  It either uses 3G/4G as the primary connection and falls back to WiFi with priority ( configured to do so ) to a WiFi connection when one is detected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EEE PC 701 is based on Intel Celeron-M which supports only SSE2 instruction set. The minimum for Android on x86 is SSE3, so some apps might use SSE3 and crash when the execution reaches any of those instructions.

Comment: This is probably it, I don't know how the gopro app is programmed, but sounds plausible.